# Fabric: running Arbitrary remote shell commands in parallel

Tags: fabric

Fabric’s arbitrary command mode allows me execute

```
$ fab [options] -- [shell command]
```

[as defined here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/usage/fab.html)

Now, how can I leverage fabric to run the commands in **parallel**? It take an awful amount of time to execute sequentially

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs on the fab command](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-P) use the -P option. For example:

```
$ fab -R role_name -P -- du
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. Rather it increased the time by x time to do a uname -a across 1000 nodes in ec2

Comment: well you should also probably set a pool size ([rtd](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-z), [and here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/usage/parallel.html)).

Comment: This worked(-z 3) but the connection hung in 2-3 minutes. wonder if the forking is creating issues

Comment: You can work with a larger pool size, which may help. How long is the command supposed to run?

Comment: Running it serially took me 25 minutes over 850 machines